# Sentry self-hosted "23.5.2" to "23.6.0" events-consumer container restarting loop (Broker: Offset out of range (broker 1001))

Tags: apache-kafka, sentry

#### Self-Hosted Version

23.6.0

#### CPU Architecture

x86_64

#### Docker Version

24.0.5

#### Docker Compose Version

2.20.2

#### Problem

So i had sentry 23.4.0 working all fine and ok and i wanted to upgrade to the latest (23.8.0) and i had read hard stops (23.6.2) and skips (23.7.0) and for more careful process i decided to update like this: 23.4.0 -> 23.4.2 -> 23.5.2 -> 23.6.2 -> 23.7.2 -> 23.8.0
Everything was going well until 23.6.2 i noticed one container "events-consumer" status is restarting. docker logs output was as follows:

```
arroyo.errors.OffsetOutOfRange: KafkaError{code=_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET,val=-140,str="fetch failed due to requested offset not available on the broker: Broker: Offset out of range (broker 1001)"}
06:31:47 [ERROR] arroyo.processing.processor: Caught exception, shutting down...
06:31:47 [INFO] arroyo.processing.processor: Closing <arroyo.backends.kafka.consumer.KafkaConsumer object at 0x7fd2d98bf670>...
06:31:47 [INFO] arroyo.processing.processor: Partitions to revoke: [Partition(topic=Topic(name='ingest-events'), index=0)]
06:31:47 [INFO] arroyo.processing.processor: Partition revocation complete.
```

So i thought may be it was fixed in the future updates and kept on going up to 23.8.0 but the container was still in restart loop. after a little research i noticed that after 23.6.0 the old "ingest-consumer" container was split into three containers which 2 of them work correctly but the "events-consumer" couldn't stay up & running.
I tried "https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/troubleshooting/#kafka" solutions and compared the LAG value of "ingest-consumer ingest-events" time to time and it was changing between 5000 and 15000. the vm has 10 core cpu and 32GB memory. i monitored the resource usage with zabbix and docker stats and made sure that it's not resource limit issue. the docker-compose also didn't define any limit for it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

#### Expected Result

events-consumer container not failing.

Comment: You'll need to look at the source code for the kafka consumer client and see what `auto.offset.reset` config is used. It'll only crash if the value is `none`

Comment: @OneCricketeer i added "--offset-auto-reset=latest" to "events-consumer" command and docker compose down and up. still restarting with same error.

Comment: I'm not sure what arguments it accepts, but compose down and up, in my experience, don't work with new options. You'll need to remove the containers first

Comment: no, it removes. 'the “docker-compose down” command is utilized to stop and remove containers, volumes, networks, and images created by “docker-compose up”.' anyway thanks for your help. i realized the problem is that i have to find a trade-off between storage cleanup policies and kafka configuration to avoid "events-consumer" failure.

Comment: I typically use `docker compose rm -sfv` (note the hyphenated version is deprecated now)